# Having trouble converting string (parsed from JSON) into javascript date object

Tags: javascript, json, date, string-parsing, date-parsing

I am trying to create javasscript date object in the following way

```
var object = {"name":"Bay Area Global Health Film Festival","start_time":"2013-07-08T19:00:00","end_time":"2013-07-08T23:45:00","timezone":"America/Los_Angeles","location":"San Francisco","id":"458415670892007","rsvp_status":"attending"}

var tempDate = date(object.start_time);
```

And I'm getting back the error:

```
date is not defined
```

I have also tried trimming the string using:

```
var tempDate = date(object.start_time.slice(0,object.start_time.indexOf("T"));
//This yields an input of 2013-07-08
```

Which throws the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this `new Date("2013-07-08T19:00:00")`. The time you are gettng seems to be in the required format so there shouldn't be issues.

Comment: Those capital D's are a doozy!

Answer (score 0):

It throws an error because js is case sensitive and there is no 'date' object.
You should use

```
var tempDate = new Date(object.start_time);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the above code you are not trying to create date object.
To create date Object you need to use **new**.

There are four ways of instantiating a date object.

```
var d = new Date();
var d = new Date(milliseconds);
var d = new Date(dateString);
var d = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
```